# cannot invoke get int on the array type comparable[ ]

Tags: java, arraylist, duplicates, syntax-error

I'm writing a method for finding whether an array has duplicates. I ran into some problem with the equals method, error at the bold line. Any adjustments I can make?

Here's some of my partial code:

```
  public boolean duplicate(){
      for (int i=0; i<data.length; i++){
          for (int j=i+1; j<data.length; j++){
              **if (data.get(i).equals(data.get(j)){**
                  return true;
              }
          }
      }
      return false;
  }
```

Comment: Please don't mix the *exception* and the *compilation error*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arrays don't have the `get(int)` method. Instead, they use the `[int]` syntax:

```
if (data[i].equals(data[j])) {
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`data.get(i)` should be used for `List` not with array it should be `data[i]`.
This will give you compilation error as `Array` can accessed through index by `[]` and does not have any `get(int index)` method.